# Unfortunately, my program does not want to replace the newline with the null terminator

Tags: c, string, char, string-comparison

I'm currently working with sockets in C, and it seems we can't get the output to buffer correctly. How it works is that a client sends a string to a server in pieces. The server waits until it finds a newline character in the string. Once it has its string, it replaces the newline character with a null terminator, then prints the buffer. The program moves the extra data to the front of the buffer and repeats the process.

Unfortunately, my program does not want to replace the newline with the null terminator.
All attempts to test the code end with the string being outputed in pieces

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>


#ifndef PORT
  #define PORT 30000
#endif


int setup(void) {
  int on = 1, status;
  struct sockaddr_in self;
  int listenfd;
  if ((listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
    perror("socket");
    exit(1);
  }

  // Make sure we can reuse the port immediately after the
  // server terminates.
  status = setsockopt(listenfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,
                      (const char *) &on, sizeof(on));
  if(status == -1) {
    perror("setsockopt -- REUSEADDR");
  }

  self.sin_family = AF_INET;
  self.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  self.sin_port = htons(PORT);
  memset(&self.sin_zero, 0, sizeof(self.sin_zero));  // Initialize sin_zero to 0

  printf("Listening on %d\n", PORT);

  if (bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *)&self, sizeof(self)) == -1) {
    perror("bind"); // probably means port is in use
    exit(1);
  }

  if (listen(listenfd, 5) == -1) {
    perror("listen");
    exit(1);
  }
  return listenfd;
}


/*
 * Search the first inbuf characters of buf for a network newline ("\r\n").
 * Return the location of the '\r' if the network newline is found,
 * or -1 otherwise.
 * Definitely do not use strchr or any other string function in here. (Why not?)
 */
int find_network_newline(const char *buf, int inbuf) {
  int i = 0;
  int found = 0;
  int location = 0;
  while(i < inbuf && found == 0){
    if(buf[i] == "\r"){
      location = i;
      found = 1;
    }
    i++;
  }
  if(found = 1){
    return location;
  }
  return -1; // return the location of '\r' if found
}


int main(void) {
  int listenfd;
  int fd, nbytes;
  char buf[30];
  int inbuf; // how many bytes currently in buffer?
  int room; // how much room left in buffer?
  char *after; // pointer to position after the (valid) data in buf
  int where; // location of network newline

  struct sockaddr_in peer;
  socklen_t socklen;

  listenfd = setup();
  while (1) {
    socklen = sizeof(peer);
    // Note that we're passing in valid pointers for the second and third
    // arguments to accept here, so we can actually store and use client
    // information.
    if ((fd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *)&peer, &socklen)) < 0) {
      perror("accept");

    } else {
      printf("New connection on port %d\n", ntohs(peer.sin_port));

      // Receive messages
      inbuf = 0;          // buffer is empty; has no bytes
      room = sizeof(buf); // room == capacity of the whole buffer
      after = buf;        // start writing at beginning of buf

      while ((nbytes = read(fd, after, room)) > 0) {
        // Step 2: update inbuf (how many bytes were just added?)
        inbuf = inbuf + nbytes;

        // Step 3: call find_network_newline, store result in variable "where"
        where = find_network_newline(buf, inbuf);

        if (where >= 0) { // OK. we have a full line

          // Step 4: output the full line, not including the "\r\n",
          // using print statement below.
          // Be sure to put a '\0' in the correct place first;
          // otherwise you'll get junk in the output.
          // (Replace the "\r\n" with appropriate characters so the
          // message prints correctly to stdout.)
          buf[where] = "\0";
          printf("Next message: %s", buf);
          // Note that we could have also used write to avoid having to
          // put the '\0' in the buffer. Try using write later!


          // Step 5: update inbuf and remove the full line from the buffer
          // There might be stuff after the line, so don't just do inbuf = 0

          // You want to move the stuff after the full line to the beginning
          // of the buffer.  A loop can do it, or you can use memmove.
          // memmove(destination, source, number_of_bytes)
      after += where;
      memmove(buf, after, 30);
      inbuf = strlen(buf);

        }
        // Step 6: update room and after, in preparation for the next read
    room = 30 - inbuf;
    after = buf;

      }
      close(fd);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: turn on compiler warnings and take the time to learn how to debug your own programs.

Comment: you don't need write, can also do `printf(" Next message: %.*s",where,buf);`

Comment: `if(buf[i] == "\r")` should generate compiler warnings.  Enable all warnings  to save us all time.

Comment: `buf[where] = "\0";` is wrong, it should be `buf[where] = '\0';`

Answer (score 2):

it is because you are comparing `buf[i]` to a string not to characther.

```
if(buf[i] == "\r")
```

should be

```
if(buf[i] == '\r')
```

and

```
buf[where] = "\0";
```

should be

```
buf[where] = '\0';
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using '\0' instead of "\0", i think it should work.

Comment: you men '\'  not '/'